# C# Filetype association

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

How can I prgramatically add an application to the Open With menu for a given file type?

E.g. I've made a simple text file viewer, I've made setup project for the same,
I want associate the text file viewer with all .txt files in system,
When a user double clicks any .txt file then my application should open.

[Open with menu http://i4.photoblog.com/photos/27294-1306838510-0.jpg](http://i4.photoblog.com/photos/27294-1306838510-0.jpg)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this great class for that: http://www.mentalis.org/soft/class.qpx?id=5

Answer (score 1):

You have to change the Registry entry: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\txtfile\shell\open\command`. Have a look with `regedit.exe`. You may also have a look at this key: `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\.txt`

To manipulate a registry entry use `System.Win32.Registry` with the [Docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.win32.registry.aspx) here.

Answer (score 1):

Here's one way (in VB) on how to do it. ApplicationTag is a short name for the registry, such as `editor3.1` . You can check the registry with regedit to see what's happening, and you may want to make a restore point before you test this part of your application.

```
Imports Microsoft.Win32
```

...

```
Registry.SetValue("HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\classes\" & FileType, "", applicationTag)
q = Registry.CurrentUser.OpenSubKey("Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Explorer\FileExts\" & FileType, True)
If q IsNot Nothing AndAlso q.GetValue("ProgID", "notfound") <> "notfound" Then
  q.SetValue("ProgID", appTag) ' for the local user, overrides hkcr
  End If
appKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\classes\" & applicationTag
Registry.SetValue(appKey, "", "text")
Registry.SetValue(appKey & "\shell", "", "open")
Registry.SetValue(appKey & "\shell\open", "", "")

Registry.SetValue(appKey & "\shell\open\command", "", """" & ApplicationPath & """ ""%1""")
Registry.SetValue(appKey, "", "text")
appKey = "HKEY_CURRENT_USER\software\classes\CLSID\" & ApplicationGuid
Registry.SetValue(appKey, "", applicationTitle)
Registry.SetValue(appKey & "\ProgID", "", applicationTag)
```